# How to get the number of fields in a boost-hana adapted struct?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-hana

Say I have the following struct:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int field1;
    float field2;
};
```

I would like to obtain the number of fields in the struct using boost-hana.

```
#include <boost/hana/adapt_struct.hpp>


BOOST_HANA_ADAPT_STRUCT(MyStruct, position, field1, field2);

// this code does not work:
constexpr std::size_t NUMBER_OF_FIELDS = boost::hana::length<MyStruct>();

static_assert(NUMBER_OF_FIELDS  == 2);
```

How to get the number of fields in a boost-hana adapted struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hana specifically aims to simplify meta-programming by lifting type functions to the constexpr domain. In plain English: you shouldn't be using `length<>` as a "type function template" but as a normal function:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ed4c68b70fd729b)**

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int position;
    int field1;
    float field2;
};

#include <boost/hana.hpp>

BOOST_HANA_ADAPT_STRUCT(MyStruct, position, field1, field2);

constexpr std::size_t NUMBER_OF_FIELDS = boost::hana::size(MyStruct{});
static_assert(NUMBER_OF_FIELDS  == 3);

int main(){}
```

Comment: This requires MyStruct to be default constructible. Which is not always the case